# Which maximum selection algorithm is faster? (Haskell)

Tags: algorithm, performance, haskell

I have a suspicion that it's the first one, but I'm not sure, and don't know how to check so I thought I'd just post here. I was also kinda lazy to provide normal examples, but the type thing
is basically irrelevant to my question.

```
data Storage = HDD String Int Int
             | SSD String Int
             deriving(Show,Eq)

maxSSD :: [Storage] -> Int -> Int
        maxSSD (HDD{}:xs) mx = maxSSD xs mx
        maxSSD [] mx = mx
        maxSSD l@((SSD _ x):xs) (-1) = maxSSD l x
        maxSSD ((SSD _ x):xs) mx
            |x>mx = maxSSD xs x
            |otherwise = maxSSD xs mx

maxSSD' :: [Storage] -> Int
        maxSSD (HDD{}:xs) = maxSSD xs
        maxSSD [] = 0
        maxSSD ((SSD _ x):xs) 
                |x>(maxSSD xs) = x
                |True = maxSSD xs
```

Comment: I don't think `maxSSD'` will even compile as written; it should be recursive, not calling `maxSSD`, correct?

Comment: @Pillsy calling self (on the reduced input) _is_ being recursive.

Comment: I'm kind of not sure the closure is right. this Q asks this about its specific code, and the algorithms: one iterative, the other recursive, not just in general like in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: maybe someone will want to comment on the strictness analyzer's impact on the performance or something... ping me if you need me to reopen this.

Comment: @ the asker: do you think the "duplicate" answers your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*NB: of course the indentation is all wrong (the signatures' indentation and definitions' should be the same), and I assume all `maxSSD`s in the second code are actually `maxSSD'`s.*

On the face of it the first is linear and the second is worst case exponential, calculating the recursive call `(maxSSD' xs)` twice in some cases.

But since that expression participates in `>` comparison, and `>` is strict in both arguments, if you compile with optimizations (`-O2`) the strictness analyzer could hopefully kick in, preventing the re-calculation of the same value.

You can test this by compiling with `-O2` and running the compiled standalone executable with `-RTS +s` to get the time and space statistics, then run it at few different problem sizes, say, doubling it each time. Then see whether the run time doubles as well.

- see also: [Empirical orders of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth)

In general we can say that the first code expresses an iterative algorithm and the second a recursive one.

A simple tweak of the second will prevent any possibility of recalculation of the same value:

Just use a `let` / `where` clause, as appropriate, to introduce a binding that holds the result of the recursive call, then refer to that variable twice. This way it is guaranteed to only be calculated once.